# i have not access to shared files in a network... needs a permission

Tags: windows-7, networking, file-sharing, file-permissions

salute..

There is a connection between my laptop and my desktop, just via a cable.
And I have shared some files, but when i try to access the files in the other one, there is an error:

> Windows cannot access \ john\files
>
> you do not have permission to access
> files.  contact your network
> administrator to request  access.

I have turned on network discovery and turned off password protection and also both are in the same group (Public) and my OS is windows 7 in both.

How can i give this permission?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you try sharing with homegroup.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a Win7 box to look at, but from within Windows Explorer do (something like) the following:

Tools > Folder Options > (2nd tab I believe) > Uncheck Simple File Sharing

Now when you try to access files from one machine to the other, it should prompt you for credentials - just use a username/password that exists on the sharing machine.

Comment: simple file sharing doesn't turn off network credentials

Comment: No, but disabling it forces a credentials prompt and lets you specify credentials, whereas when it's on you either connect or don't based on the sharing password. Basically "Simple File Sharing" complicates the troubleshooting process. And the OP wasn't asking turning on/off network credentials, only about "giving permission", which entering a valid username/password would do.